# How to set multiselect value in jquery

Tags: magento2, multiselect

I've follow this solution to make multiselect works without using "Ctrl" in keyboard.

http://jsfiddle.net/xQqbR/1022/

And here's the result:
[image]

Its work great, but i can't save in database.

 As far as i debug, the values of this multiselect are correct, but when i click "Save Vendor", its post the old values of multiselect.

I thing it's because of this simple solution doesn't work with ui component.
[image]

How to solve this? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fount it. 
So my solution is each time the option is clicked, we add the option value to a html tag called **data-new**, then we catch that **data-new** in *multiselect.js*, and replace it with **data**, which will be saved to the database some how. 
To do this, you will need 2 js files.
Note: *shipping_methods_no_free* is attribute code

> web/js/custom.js

```
require([
    'jquery'
], function ($) {
    'use strict';
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        $(document).on('mousedown', 'div[data-index="shipping_methods_no_free"] select', function(e){
            // use mousedown instead of change, don't know why
            var currentData = [];
            if ($(this).attr('data-new') === undefined) {
                // first load
                currentData = $(this).val();
            } else if ($(this).attr('data-new') === "") {
                // if data-new is null
                currentData = [];
            } else if ($(this).attr('data-new') !== "") {
                // if data-new is not null
                currentData = $(this).attr('data-new').split(',');
            }
            var selected = e.target.value;

            if ($.inArray(selected, currentData) !== -1) {
                // remove selected from array
                currentData = jQuery.grep(currentData, function(value) {
                    return value != selected;
                });

                // style the option again, use linear-gradient and -webkit-text-fill-color to pass "user agent stylesheet" problem
                $('div[data-index="shipping_methods_no_free"] select option[value="' + selected + '"]')
                    .css('background', 'linear-gradient(#FFF, #FFF)');
                $('div[data-index="shipping_methods_no_free"] select option')
                    .css('-webkit-text-fill-color', 'rgb(16, 16, 16)');
            } else {
                // add selected to array
                currentData.push(selected);

                // style the option again, use linear-gradient and -webkit-text-fill-color to pass "user agent stylesheet" problem
                var i;
                for (i = 0; i < currentData.length; ++i) {
                    $('div[data-index="shipping_methods_no_free"] select option[value="' + currentData[i] + '"]')
                        .css('background', 'linear-gradient(rgb(206, 206, 206), rgb(206, 206, 206))')
                        .css('-webkit-text-fill-color', 'rgb(16, 16, 16)');
                }
                $('div[data-index="shipping_methods_no_free"] select option[value="' + selected + '"]')
                    .css('-webkit-text-fill-color', '#fff');
            }

            $(this).attr('data-new', currentData.toString());
        }).on('mousemove', 'div[data-index="shipping_methods_no_free"] select', function(e){e.preventDefault()});
    });
});
```

> Magento_Ui/web/js/form/element/multiselect.js

other contents of this file are the same, only need to override *setPrepareToSendData()*

```
        setPrepareToSendData: function (data) {
            if (_.isUndefined(data) || !data.length) {
                data = '';
            }

            // START custom
            var element = document.getElementsByName('vendor[shipping_methods_no_free]');
            if (element.length) {
                // custom add new data so it can post the correct data.
                var newData = element[0].getAttribute('data-new');
                var newData = newData.split(",");
                data = newData;
            }
            // END custom

            this.source.set(this.dataScope + '-prepared-for-send', newData);
        },
```